# Problem with sending HTML in email from Outlook to Gmail. The last two parts are not rendered but a base64 string shows up at the bottom

Tags: html, css, outlook, gmail, html-email

So when said HTML is sent via Outlook to another Outlook inbox, it works just fine but when the recipient is Gmail, the following parts do not get rendered:

[image]

I get the following code at the bottom. The code seems to be backend stuff after I decoded the base64 string.

[image: This is the code that shows up at the end of the message]

What's going on here? The code is shown below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">


<head>


<meta charset="utf-8">




<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">


<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">


<!--[if !mso]><!-->


<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />


<!--<![endif]-->


<title></title>


<!--[if mso]>


<style type="text/css">


table {border-collapse:collapse;border:0;border-spacing:0;margin:0;}


div, td {padding:0;}


div {margin:0 !important;}


</style>


<noscript>


<xml>


<o:OfficeDocumentSettings>


<o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>


</o:OfficeDocumentSettings>


</xml>


</noscript>


<![endif]-->


</head>


<body style="margin:0;padding:0;word-spacing:normal;background-color:#ffffff;">


<div role="article" aria-roledescription="email" lang="en" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;background-color:#ffffff;">


<table role="presentation" style="width:100%;border:0;border-spacing:0;">


<tr>


<td align="center">


<!--[if mso]>


<table role="presentation" align="center" style="width:660px;">


<tr>


<td style="padding:20px 0;">


<![endif]-->


<div class="outer" style="width:100%;max-width:660px;margin:0px auto;">


<table role="presentation" style="width:100%;border:0;border-spacing:0;">


<tr style="font-size: 0px;">


<td style="font-size:0px;display: inline;font-weight:bold;">


<img src="https://i.ibb.co/D1x1nNH/e.png" width="600" alt="" style="width:100%;max-width: 99.9%;" />


</td>


</tr>


<tr>


<td style="padding:0px 10px;text-align:left;background-color: #08197C;color: #ffffff;line-height: 1.4;">


<p style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;text-align: center;font-size: 35px;margin: 15px 0px;">Cashku Save's daily return rate


increased again!</p>


</td>


</tr>


<tr>


<td style="padding:0px 10px;text-align:left;background-color: #00EBCF;color: #08197C;line-height: 1.5;">


<p style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS';font-weight:bold;text-align: center;font-size: 25px;">


We just bumped up our daily return rate from 3.5%*p.a to 3.93%* p.a!</p>


</td>


</tr>


<tr>


<td style="padding:0px 10px;text-align:left;background-color: #00EBCF;color: #08197C;line-height: 1.5;">


<p style="margin:0px 0px 25px 0px;font-family:'Trebuchet MS';font-weight:bold;text-align: center;font-size: 25px;">






So,if you maintain a balance of RM 10,000 for 12 months,you will earn about RM 393 at the end of the term.</p>


</td>


</tr>


<tr>


<td style="padding:15px 10px;text-align:left;background-color: #08197C;color: #ffffff;line-height: 1.3;">


<p style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;text-align: center;font-size: 18px;">And here are some other reasons you should save in Cashku Save:</p>


</td>


</tr>


</table>


<!-- two column -->


<div class="two-col" style="text-align:center;font-size:0;background-color: #08197C;">


<!--[if mso]>


<table role="presentation" width="100%">


<tr>


<td style="width:50%;padding:10px;text-align:left;" valign="middle">


<![endif]-->


<div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:330px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">


<div style="padding:10px 30px;">


<p style="margin:0;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;">


<img src="https://i.ibb.co/nQZttdJ/Better-Returns-logo-2nd-page.png" width="100%" alt="" style="display:block;width:150px;max-width:100%;height:auto;max-width: 100%;display: inline-block;" />


</p>


<p style="font-size: 20px;color: #F37032;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;">BETTER RETURNS</p>


<p style="font-size: 17.5px;color: #ffffff;font-size: 18px;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;line-height: 1.4;">Earn 3.93%* p.a returns with


Cashku Save as opposed to


2.45%* p.a returns in Fixed


Deposits</p>


</div>


</div>


<!--[if mso]>


</td>


<td style="width:50%;padding:10px;text-align:left;" valign="middle">


<![endif]-->


<div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:330px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">


<div style="padding:10px 30px;">


<p style="margin:0;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:1.4;">


<img src="https://i.ibb.co/B2w30PJ/Shariah-Compliant-logo-2nd-page.png" width="145px" alt="" style="display:block;max-width:100%;height:auto;max-width: 100%;display: inline-block;" />


</p>


<p style="font-size: 20px;color: #F37032;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;">SHARIAH COMPLIANT</p>


<p style="font-size: 15px;color: #ffffff;font-size: 18px;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;line-height: 1.4;">Cashku Save is Shariah


Compliant! Have a


worry-free mind when


saving with Cashku Save</p>


</div>


</div>


<!--[if mso]>


</td>










</tr>


</table>


<![endif]-->


</div>


<!-- two column again -->


<div class="two-col" style="text-align:center;font-size:0;background-color: #08197C;">


<!--[if mso]>


<table role="presentation" width="100%">


<tr>


<td style="width:50%;padding:10px;text-align:left;" valign="middle">


<![endif]-->


<div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:330px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">


<div style="padding:10px 30px;">


<p style="margin:0;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;">


<img src="https://i.ibb.co/SK3GFWD/Transferable-Logo-2nd-page.png" width="200px" alt="" style="display:block;width:200px;max-width:100%;height:auto;max-width: 100%;display: inline-block;" />


</p>


<p style="font-size: 20px;color: #F37032;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;">TRANSFERABLE</p>


<p style="font-size: 17.5px;color: #ffffff;font-size: 18px;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;line-height: 1.4;">Earn money in Cashku Save and cash out to your bank account at any time</p>


</div>


</div>


<!--[if mso]>


</td>


<td style="width:50%;padding:10px;text-align:left;" valign="middle">


<![endif]-->


<div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:330px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">


<div style="padding:10px 30px;">


<p style="margin:0;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:1.4;">


<img src="https://i.ibb.co/8gjmv6r/ONLY-10-to-start-Logo-2nd-page.png" width="180px" alt="" style="height:auto;max-width: 100%;display: inline-block;" />


</p>


<p style="font-size: 20px;color: #F37032;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;">ONLY RM10 TO START!</p>


<p style="font-size: 15px;color: #ffffff;font-size: 18px;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;line-height: 1.4;padding: 0px 25px;">Start saving with Cashku Save for as low as RM10!</p>


</div>


</div>


<!--[if mso]>


</td>










</tr>


</table>


<![endif]-->


</div>


<table role="presentation" style="width:100%;border:0;border-spacing:0;">






<tr>


<td style="padding:20px 20px;text-align:left;background-color: #08197C;color: #ffffff;line-height: 1.3;">


<p style="margin:0px;line-height:1.8;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;text-align: center;font-size: 20px;">Now you can start saving and make your money work harder


than ever before!</p>


</td>


</tr>






<tr>


<td style="padding:0px 10px;text-align:left;background-color: #08197C;color: #ffffff;line-height: 1.3;">


<p style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;text-align: center;font-size: 38px;margin: 20px 0px;"><a href="https://cashku.my/" style="color: #00EBCF;text-decoration-color:#00EBCF ;text-decoration-thickness: 5px;">TAKE ME TO CASHKU SAVE</a></p>


</td>


</tr>


<tr>


<td style="padding:0px 50px;text-align:left;background-color: #08197C;color: #ffffff;line-height: 1.3;">


<p style="margin:0px;line-height:1.8;font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;text-align: center;font-size: 15px;color: #cecac9;">Terms and conditions apply.</p>


</td>


</tr>


<tr>


<td style="padding:0px 10px;text-align:left;background-color: #08197C;color: #ffffff;line-height: 1.3;">


<p style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;text-align: center;font-size: 38px;margin: 20px 0px 40px 0px;">If you have questions:</p>


</td>


</tr>


</table>


<div class="two-col" style="text-align:center;font-size:0;background-color: #08197C;padding: 30px 0px;">


<!--[if mso]>


<table role="presentation" width="100%">


<tr>


<td style="width:50%;padding:10px;text-align:left;" valign="middle">


<![endif]-->


<div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:330px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">


<div style="padding:10px;">


<p style="margin:0;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;">


<img src="https://i.ibb.co/zswVNPm/faq.png" width="100%" alt="" style="display:block;width:200px;max-width:100%;height:auto;max-width: 100%;display: inline-block;" />


</p>










</div>


</div>


<!--[if mso]>


</td>


<td style="width:50%;padding:10px;text-align:left;" valign="middle">


<![endif]-->


<div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:330px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">


<div style="padding:10px 20px; ">


<p style="margin:0;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;">


<img src="https://i.ibb.co/tJWkDvR/first.png" width="100%" alt="" style="display:block;width:200;max-width:100%;height:auto;max-width: 100%;display: inline-block;" />


</p>


<p style="margin:10px;font-size: 18px ;line-height:1.5;color: #ffffff;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;">refer to our <a href="https://cashku.my/#faqs" style="color: #ffffff;text-decoration-thickness: 2px;">frequently asked


questions!</a> </p>


</div>


</div>


<!--[if mso]>


</td>










</tr>


</table>


<![endif]-->


</div>


<!-- whatapps two column -->


<div class="two-col" style="text-align:center;font-size:0;background-color: #08197C;padding: 30px 0px;">


<!--[if mso]>


<table role="presentation" width="100%">


<tr>


<td style="width:50%;padding:10px;text-align:left;" valign="middle">


<![endif]-->


<div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:330px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">


<div style="padding:10px;">


<p style="margin: 0px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;">


<img src="https://i.ibb.co/Jrx17JL/whatsapp-logo-3rd-page.png" width="100%" alt="" style="display:block;width:200px;max-width:100%;height:auto;max-width: 100%;display: inline-block;" />


</p>










</div>


</div>


<!--[if mso]>


</td>


<td style="width:50%;padding:10px;text-align:left;" valign="middle">


<![endif]-->


<div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:330px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">


<div style="padding:10px 40px 10px 10px">


<p style="margin:0;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;text-align: left;">


<img src="https://i.ibb.co/hytSD2M/whatapps.png" width="300px" alt="" style="display:block;max-width:100%;height:auto;max-width: 100%;display: inline-block;" />


</p>


<p style="margin:10px 0px 10px 0px ;font-size: 15px;color: #ffffff;font-size: 25px;line-height: 1.5;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;">Want to know more?


<a href="" style="color: #ffffff;">Whatsapp us now!</a> </p>


</div>


</div>


<!--[if mso]>


</td>










</tr>


</table>


<![endif]-->


</div>


<!-- Email two column -->


<div class="two-col" style="text-align:center;font-size:0;background-color: #08197C;">


<!--[if mso]>


<table role="presentation" width="100%">


<tr>


<td style="width:50%;padding:10px;text-align:left;" valign="middle">


<![endif]-->


<div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:330px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">


<div style="padding:10px;">


<p style="margin:0;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;">


<img src="https://i.ibb.co/xXTHdmL/message.png" width="100%" alt="" style="display:block;width:200px;max-width:100%;height:auto;max-width: 100%;display: inline-block;" />


</p>










</div>


</div>


<!--[if mso]>


</td>


<td style="width:50%;padding:10px;text-align:left;" valign="middle">


<![endif]-->


<div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:330px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;">


<div style="padding:10px 60px 10px 10px">


<p style="margin:0; font-size:14px;line-height:18px;text-align: center;">


<img src="https://i.ibb.co/tYXkgYB/email.png" width="450px" alt="" style="display:block;width:250;max-width:100%;height:auto;max-width: 100%;display: inline-block;" />


</p>


<p style="margin:0px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 15px;color: #ffffff;font-size: 25px;line-height: 1.5;">Email us if you have any


questions!</p>


<p style="margin:25px 0px 10px 0px;font-size: 15px;color: #ffffff;font-size: 25px;line-height: 1.5;"><a href="#" style="color:#ffffff">hello@cashku.my</a> </p>


</div>


</div>


<!--[if mso]>


</td>










</tr>


</table>


<![endif]-->


</div>


<!-- promotional two column -->


<div class="two-col" style="text-align:center;font-size:0;background-color: #08197C;padding: 20px 0px;">


<!--[if mso]>


<table role="presentation" width="100%">


<tr>


<td style="width:50%;padding:10px 10px 10px 60px;text-align:left;" valign="middle">


<![endif]-->


<div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:330px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">


<div style="padding:10px 10px 10px 60px; ">


<p style="margin:0;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;">


<img src="./get it on google play.png" width="300px" alt="" style="display:block;max-width:100%;height:auto;max-width: 100%;display: inline-block;" />


</p>










</div>


</div>


<!--[if mso]>


</td>


<td style="width:50%;padding:10px 60px 10px 10px;text-align:left;" valign="middle">


<![endif]-->


<div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:330px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">


<div style="padding:10px 60px 10px 10px;">


<p style="margin:0;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;">


<img src="app store .png" width="300px" alt="" style="display:block;height:auto;max-width: 100%;display: inline-block;" /></p>


</div>


</div>


<!--[if mso]>


</td>










</tr>


</table>


<![endif]-->


</div>


<!-- footer section -->


<table role="presentation" style="width:100%;border:0;border-spacing:0;">






<tr>


<td style="padding:0px 10px;text-align:left;background-color: #08197C;color: #ffffff;line-height: 1.3;">


<p style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;text-align: center;font-size: 20px;margin: 10px 0px 20px 0px;"><a href="" style="color: #ffffff;"> https://cashku.my/#contact</a></p>


<p style="text-align: center;font-size: 16px;margin: 8px 0px 30px 0px;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;"> 2023 Advisonomics Sdn. Bhd (1350910-W). All rights reserved.</p>


</td>


</tr>














</table>


</div>


<!--[if mso]>


</td>


</tr>


</table>


<![endif]-->


</td>


</tr>


</table>


</div>


</body>


</html>
```

I tried adding a ;base64 to the image source tag to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Outlook.com (and Outlook on macOS, iOS or Android) support Base 64 images. Gmail does not.

[image: Can I email… Base 64 image format]

Comment: Right, yeah but the images arent actually encoded in base64. The img src isn't coded in base64 as the original code shows. Which is why I'm confused as to why this img tag shows up that seems to be coded in base64 shows up.

Comment: For the img to be coded in base64, wouldn't it require a ;base64 string at the src? Because the original image is in png format

Comment: It looks like it's this one, which the src is not done correctly: src="./get it on google play.png"